# slow performance and outofmemory exception in some conditions

Tags: android, user-interface, imageview, apk

I am a bit new to android and developing an app which has 10 full screen background imageviews . after a while working with the app it force closes because of outOfMemory exception. I got every image in the 720 × 1200 px from photoshop designer. I haven't put different sizes of images in drawable-dpi folders since I am confused how to scale. where am I supposed to put this 720 × 1200 ? in which drawable folder ? Any help or clear explanation would be appreciated . Tnx in advance .

Comment: As @Devsil says having different images in different folders does not solve your issue. the issue is you need to scale your image to the size of the image view. loading a 720x1200 image into memory takes up 3.5mb for one image ( (720x1200)x4 ) which isn't a lot but you didn't give any information in how you are presenting the images

Comment: These images are just background of some layouts and I set them in xml by using Imageview since they are not going to be changed dynamically . sorry I donot understand you by the last sentence you said . can you explain what u mean ?  @tyczj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont think the solution you are looking for is to use the different drawable resource folders for different screen densities but instead you should check this link: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html on how to load the bitmaps more efficiently by downsampling before you load them into the Image View and by making sure you release any bitmap that isn't being used any longer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create different dimen , layout , images and icon files to support all devices.

**changes in screen density.**

```
xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp
```

**Make this layout files, so that it will be same for all devices**.

Give padding ,margin ,font and all properties as per devices.

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For handsets (smaller than 600dp available width)
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)
```

**For Layout** ,

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml              // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml        // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml       // layout for extra-large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml  // layout for extra-large in landscape orientation
```

---

**For Images**

```
res/drawable-mdpi/graphic.png         // bitmap for medium-density
res/drawable-hdpi/graphic.png         // bitmap for high-density
res/drawable-xhdpi/graphic.png        // bitmap for extra-high-density
res/drawable-xxhdpi/graphic.png       // bitmap for extra-extra-high-density
```

---

**For Icon**

```
res/mipmap-mdpi/my_icon.png         // launcher icon for medium-density
res/mipmap-hdpi/my_icon.png         // launcher icon for high-density
res/mipmap-xhdpi/my_icon.png        // launcher icon for extra-high-density
res/mipmap-xxhdpi/my_icon.png       // launcher icon for extra-extra-high-density
res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/my_icon.png      // launcher icon for extra-extra-extra-high-density
```

**For Launcher icon**

```
36x36 (0.75x) for low-density
48x48 (1.0x baseline) for medium-density
72x72 (1.5x) for high-density
96x96 (2.0x) for extra-high-density
180x180 (3.0x) for extra-extra-high-density
192x192 (4.0x) for extra-extra-extra-high-density (launcher icon only; see note above)
```

Checkout [Dimension](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension) and 
[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/practices/screens_support.html) Official Documentaion.

Comment: Thats a good explanation of supporting mutlple screen densities but I believe the OP issue resides in loading the full bitmaps and not releasing them when he's finished with them. Which is why after a few are loaded the app will eventually OOM.

Comment: He can try using Glide, this lib sometime helps you control the Images and don't get a OOM

Comment: Glide, Picasso, Fresco, etc. Any of those would work (my personal fav is Fresco). It also may be overkill to use any of those libraries if all he is attempting to do with Bitmaps is what he is currently doing.

Comment: I have set background to all imageviews in xml since it is fixed full screen and not dynamic . so what you say is to use bitmaps in order to scaling those images ? @Devsil

Comment: Yes, I would review the link I posted in my answer. That is focused on using Bitmaps efficiently and is very easy to follow/understand even for a beginner. It may be more work then just including the image in the imageView xml creation but ultimately it is better practice and still isn't a ton of work to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks alot . I thought I have to have different sizes of those images since all I have now is 720 × 1200 px images . The exception wont be appeared when setting largeheap true in manifest but I donot like this way because it is not a real solution .